# Need to plot images in a chart using Angular2

Tags: angular, charts, google-visualization, devextreme, devextreme-angular

I need to plot images like a timeline view/chart with start and end timestamps on x-axis.
The below image contains 3 PNG images and each image has start and end timestamps.
Please find the below screenshot for reference.
[image]

My Datapoint looks like below

```
this.audioData = [{
    startTimestamp: 1515096303610,
    endTimestamp: 1515096903667,
    position: 1,
    image: 'assets/img/audio-image1.png'
}, {
    startTimestamp: 1515096903667,
    endTimestamp: 1515097503607,
    position: 1,
    image: 'assets/img/audio-image1.png'
}, {
     startTimestamp: 1515096903667,
    endTimestamp: 1515096903670,
    position: 1,
    image: 'assets/img/audio-image3.png'
}];
}
```

**Note:** I am currently using google charts and dev extreme charts if any way on using those two will be more helpful. If any other charts with same requirements also fine.
Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Why do you want to combine these pictures with chart control?

Comment: I need to visualize these images in a chart to see the audio status in timely manner.